# ImproperlyConfigured("The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.")

Tags: django

when I run "`python manage.py run server`" it gives following error

```
ImproperlyConfigured("The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.")
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.
```

I am using django version 1.6.5.
Thank you.

Comment: Go to your settings.py file and check that the SECRET_KEY value is there.

Comment: Step 1 in solving an error: **Read the error message.**

Comment: [Here](http://www.miniwebtool.com/django-secret-key-generator/) you can generate a secret key online.

Comment: This is curious because django creates a secret key for you when you start a project.  see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#secret-key  Did you delete it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your settings.py file SECRET_KEY would be empty.
you have to add some secret key in SECRET_KEY in settings.py file of your project.